# JavaFX chart move data

Tags: java, animation, javafx, charts

I want to create a chart like this:
X Axis: 0-60 in seconds (0 is now)
Y Axis: Values from -1 to 6
So every new value (updates every second) appears at the left, then moves along the x axis until 60 and disappears there.

I've only seen people moving the point of view and expanding the chart, but not moving the data, so how do I do that.
I tried updating the values every 25ms to create an flawless animation, but this ended up in extreme lags.

Comment: When you add a new point, add it at the beginning and update all the other points' x values. You need to show some code if you can't get it to work.

Comment: @James_D I know this would, but there's a problem with the animation, the data would just "teleport" to the next position, and the whole thing is still very laggy. If I increase the number of updates per second to remove the teleporting effect, it doesn't work at all (it just shows random stuff). I need a way to use an JavaFX Animation, but I have no Idea how